# making a string position constant

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make 9 line of string which will be changed according to the user clicks in html:

```
<div id="moves">
    <p id = "one">text</p>
    <p id = "two">text</p>
    <p id = "tree">text</p>
    <p id = "four">text</p>
    <p id = "five">text</p>
    <p id = "six">text</p>
    <p id = "seven">text</p>
    <p id = "eight">text</p>
    <p id = "nine">text</p>
</div>


#moves {
    float: right;
    position:absolute;
    top:30%;
    right:50%;
    font-size:30px;

}
p{
    margin:0;

}
```

the problem is when i change the value of the first `<p>` all my `<p>`'s moves to the center of the screen, how can i make its position constant even after the change?

Comment: what do you mean by 's ? Also share the JS code for changing the text

Comment: How are you changing the text? or moving them? using Javascript or jQuery?

Comment: i meant paragraphs, and javascript

Comment: You need to provide your jQuery/Javascript code for us, so we'll know better what you're trying to do.

Comment: 'function setMessage(msg){
  document.getElementById("one").innerText = msg;
  
}'

Comment: And how you're changing the `msg`?

Comment: Looks like you want your main div centered, but it's content aligned left or right side right?

Comment: the message changes correctly the text just repositions..

Comment: Instead of `right: 50%` use `left: 50%`.

Comment: Did either of the answers help you? If so, please don't forget to mark one as accepted! If you still need help, please elaborate on your problem so we can further assist. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are rendering in center by default on the first load. Change your css like this

```
#moves {
    /* float: right; */
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    /* right: 50%; */
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

and the text stays as it is.

Comment: but i need it to always be 
    right: 50%;
is it possible with this?

Comment: you can fix the width of your <P> and do a text-align: right; on that.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS rule `right: 50%` means that the ***right*** side of the element will be 50% of the way from the right side of the parent element. The desired behavior you're describing seems like you want the ***left*** hand side of the element to be 50% of the way from the right side of the parent element. This is the only way that the text wouldn't shift when you add a longer line.

In that case, you will want to use `left: 50%` instead of `right: 50%`. The rules `left: 50%` and `right: 50%` both specify effectively the same place on the parent element, it's just that `left: 50%` positions the child's left side at that position, and `right: 50%` positions the child's right side at that position.

**Live Demo:**

```css
#moves {
    position:absolute;
    top:30%;
    left:50%;
    font-size:30px;
}

p{
    margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="moves">
    <p id = "one">text text text text</p>
    <p id = "two">text</p>
    <p id = "tree">text</p>
    <p id = "four">text</p>
    <p id = "five">text</p>
    <p id = "six">text</p>
    <p id = "seven">text</p>
    <p id = "eight">text</p>
    <p id = "nine">text</p>
</div>
```